# Trouble setting up chef-client on a vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef

I've been using opscode chef for remote configuration and I wanted to test my chef scripts locally, so I started working on setting up a vagrant box. But, I can't seem to get my vagrant boxes to register. I get errors like the ones listed here: https://gist.github.com/2961246

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "lucid32"

  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/pinedesk"
   chef.validation_key_path = ".chef/pinedesk-validator.pem"
   chef.validation_client_name = "pinedesk-validator"
   chef.node_name = "vagrant"
   chef.provisioning_path = "/etc/chef"
   chef.log_level = :debug

   chef.add_role "base"
  end
end
```

And my .chef folder has these:

```
dsummersl.pem
knife.rb
pinedesk-validator.pem
vagrant.pem
```

Chef appears appears to register a new client, and then gets an HTTP 401 when creating the node. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to register a new client by a name that already exists.

If you run `knife client list` you should see a client name that matches your vagrant vm's host name

Assuming the hostname is 'vagrant' you could run this:

`for foo in client node ; do knife $foo delete vagrant -y ; done`

then run `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision`

You will probably want to delete the client and node after every `vagrant destroy`

Comment: Cassiano Leal's [vagrant-butcher](https://github.com/cassianoleal/vagrant-butcher) [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/vagrant-butcher) ensures that nodes and clients associated with your Vagrant VMs are deleted when the VMs are destroyed.

Comment: Is there a way not to delete client, but reuse an existing one?